# grounding a moving robot

Tags: battery-charging, ground, safety, grounding

I'm am designing an external battery pack for a robot, Pepper, a robot by Softbank (I'm am not making the battery itself but the circuit connecting two batteries). I am going to connect a 25V (LiFe-PO4) battery to Pepper's internal (Li-ion) battery and strap it to its back. Due to the delicacy of (Li-ion) batteries I included a voltage regulator. But I also want a ground in this circuit, in case of a short circuit or anything.

**The problem is:** Pepper is a moving robot, so a real ground isn't possible. I was wondering whether it *is possible to use its (small) metal chassis as an earth. Similarly like they do in cars.*
(Just wiring the - to the chassis)
Pepper is a robot which is about 1,4m high, and only has a metal chassis in it's base, which is about 40cm broad and 20 cm high

If this is not advisable, is there another way of making the circuit more safe? (I am already going to include a fuse.)

---

External battery specs:

```
-Capacity 10Ah

-Output voltage25,6V

-Maximum pulse discharge 55A

-Maximum continuous discharge 15A
```

---

Internal battery specs:

```
-Capacity  30Ah

-Max charge current 8A

-Max charge voltage 29,4V
```

---

P.S.
Any other tips about my project are more then welcome

Comment: Why do you think you have to ground your robot?

Comment: Who is *Pepper?* The robot?
Seriously though, it seems like you are under the assumption that "grounding" the robot will make it "safer". If you're referring to making it safer for humans, I doubt your 24V battery poses any real threat (unless the cells rupture).

Comment: Pepper indeed is a robot used to amuse and interact with the elderly, only problem is it's battery life, hence my project. Since pepper is a robot who actively interacts with people (shake hands and such) it needs to be completely safe. We don't want people to get shocked after all. And yes I do think not getting shocked is a safety matter.

Comment: Ok, but no amount of "grounding" is going to make it safer. If you understood DerStrom8's answer, you'd realize that "grounding" a chassis does not make your DC battery system necessarily safer. It doesn't prevent shorts or whatever you seem to think it does. If anything, actually, it could make shorts more problematic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a moving object you can not normally have a true ground. There is one exception where the wheels are conductive and the device is moving over a metal floor or rails, but I'm going to ignore that here.

With an isolated system providing safety to users involves providing sufficient isolation to ensure that both the "positive" and "negative" side of the power source are never presented to the user. If the thing were in a metal enclosure, connecting that enclosure to either the positive or the negative side of the battery would be acceptable provided nothing exposed of the opposite polarity pokes through that enclosure.

Either way, and with a partly non conductive chassis, you need to ensure that any metal parts the user may come into contact with are either double insulated or are connected to the same terminal as the metal parts of the chassis.

The voltages in question here are non-lethal, however, you also have to be concerned about a hard short caused by some inadvertent metallic connection between exposed "terminals." Such a connection will result in a mighty spark, even with a fused power supply.

If this device is intended for out-door use, you should also consider what measures you need to take to prevent water from reaching exposed and connected metal parts.

One other thing you need to consider is static build-up on the robot. With an isolated system a significant charge can build up, kilovolts, between the chassis and the floor it stands on. That charge, will give anyone that touches it a shock, and that discharge may interfere with the operation and reliability of the robot. As such, use of a high impedance discharge belt that hangs under the robot and drags on the ground may be prudent. However, that aspect is and entirely different issue and not related to the battery isolation. Since it is intermittent at best, it should never be relied upon as a safety ground.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as a "real ground", or perhaps I should say there's no such thing as a "fake ground". A "ground" is a reference point. It's arbitrary. You can even pick the '+' side of your battery as "ground" if you want to. The purpose of "ground" is to give you a point relative to which you measure voltage. In a closed system like your robot the negative side of your battery will serve just fine as "ground".

If you want to protect your robot against lightning strikes, then you'll need an earth ground, but that's only because earth is probably the biggest body of electrons you're going to find around here, and that's what the lightning is going to want to strike. In the case of a basic robot though, just use the chassis and connect the chassis to the battery '-'.

Comment: My pleasure. Did I answer your question?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. So to sum it up, you are saying that simply connecting the external battery's - to the chassis should be enough to prevent current from building up in the robot, thus preventing the users from getting shocked?

Comment: @Joep - Current does not just "build up". DerStrom8 never said nor implied that.

Comment: @Bort I know, but im am saying **if** some sort of current or static charge would build up. Due to a misfiring or something else. Since the charge has nowhere else to go because of the rubber wheels.

Comment: @Joep Current cannot 'build up.' There is no if.

Comment: @Joep - Static voltage can build up, yes, but a grounded chassis doesn't solve that. How many times can we say that? *Again*: Consider that a chassis that is connected to ground poses an issue if someone touches a positively charged component and the chassis at the same time, because the person will complete a circuit. If the chassis is disconnected, the person is safer because now the chassis isn't part of the circuit. But it probably won't matter at 24V!

Comment: @Joep - Sorry, but your understanding of electricity is limited and that makes it very difficult for us to help you. You seem to think that current magically builds up and that your 24V battery will shock someone unless the chassis is grounded. We have explained that "grounding" doesn't help, but you appear not to grasp that yet. You should really learn the fundamentals before you start making decisions. I'm not sure what you're doing for your project or why, but you need to read about circuits. Start with V=IR and work your way up from there.

Comment: @Bort static buildup is a separate issue here, but is still important. A discharge strap may still be prudent for that reason.

Answer (score 1):

A car chassis is insulated from earth because of the rubber wheels. The chassis is 'ground', i.e. battery negative--the common reference point for the car's electronics. It's more convenient to connect to chassis than to connect a wire back to battery negative. Having the whole chassis connected to battery negative also ensures that wiring faults to chassis (as caused by wire chafing) cause large current flow, which blows fuses and breaks the circuit.

('Earth' is the dirt underneath the car. 'Earthing' a car's chassis is to connect it to the dirt.)

Your system voltages are not hazardous. Should the unit become energized to 30V, nothing will happen. Adding a chassis ground does not mitigate any shock risk because there is no shock risk in the first place.

The biggest hazard in your system is the battery. It likely contains internal protections to prevent it from overheating/exploding. You can stick a fuse in series with it to ensure that current doesn't exceed expected limits.

Comment: That last part is exactly my problem. I am working with two bare batteries who don't have any safety features built in. That's why im am trying to take as many precautions as possible. Thanks for your answer tho. Not sure if I agree on the "earth part" by the way, I believe earthing is the European term for grounding.

Comment: @Joep What makes you think that chassis ground is relevant to battery safety?